# Grafana and Date Variable dropdown

Tags: variables, dynamic, grafana

Dashboard has variable that shows date in desc order from postgres.
As days pass by, the dropdown default date still shows as the last saved date.

How can I make sure that when user picks the dashboard, it shows the report for the most recent date in the variable dropdown?

NOTE: The date may not be current_date. It's just the first date in the query result that the report should open to.

Answer (score 0):

Edit dashboard json manually (there is no UI option for that) and remove definition of default value for that particular dashboard variable. Grafana will use first result value in this case. Of course, don't save variable selection from the UI.

Comment: Thanks. I update data on my grafana app weekly, I will test this during this weekend's data update to see the before and after to see and confirm if there are any issues.

Comment: Thanks in advance.